# 'PlayerControls.photonView' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

What needs to be fixed?
I'm wasting my time finding a mistake, but it's all unsuccessful, what do I have to do?

> Error: Assets\MapController.cs(54,31): error CS0122: 'PlayerControls.photonView' is inaccessible due to its protection level

```
using ExitGames.Client.Photon;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapController : MonoBehaviour, IOnEventCallback
{
    public GameObject CellPrefab;

    private GameObject[,] cells;
    private List<PlayerControls> players = new List<PlayerControls>();

    private double lastTickTime;

    public void AddPlayer(PlayerControls player)
    {

        players.Add(player);

        cells[player.GamePosition.x, player.GamePosition.y].SetActive(false);

    }

    private void Start()
    {
        cells = new GameObject[20, 10];

        for (int x = 0; x < cells.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
            for (int y = 0; y < cells.GetLength(1); y++)
            {

                cells[x, y] = Instantiate(CellPrefab, new Vector3(x, y), Quaternion.identity, transform);

            }

        }
    }


   private void Update()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.Time > lastTickTime + 1 &&
            PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient &&
            PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == 2)
        {

            Vector2Int[] directions = players
                .OrderBy(p=>p.photonView.Owner.ActorNumber)
                .Select(p=>p.Direction)
                .ToArray();

            RaiseEventOptions options = new RaiseEventOptions { Receivers = ReceiverGroup.Others };
            SendOptions sendOptions = new SendOptions { Reliability = true };
            PhotonNetwork.RaiseEvent(42, directions, options, sendOptions);

            PerformTick(directions);
        }
    }
    public void OnEvent(EventData photonEvent)
    {

        switch (photonEvent.Code)
        {

            case 42:
                Vector2Int[] directions = (Vector2Int[]) photonEvent.CustomData;

                PerformTick(directions);

                break;

        }

    }
    private void PerformTick(Vector2Int[] directions) 
    {
        if (players.Count != directions.Length) return;

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var player in players.OrderBy(p=>p.photonView.Owner.ActorNumber))
        {

            player.Direction = directions[i++];

            player.GamePosition += player.Direction;

            if (player.GamePosition.x < 0) player.GamePosition.x = 0;
            if (player.GamePosition.y < 0) player.GamePosition.y = 0;
            if (player.GamePosition.x >= cells.GetLength(0)) player.GamePosition.x = cells.GetLength(0)-1;
            if (player.GamePosition.y >= cells.GetLength(1)) player.GamePosition.y = cells.GetLength(1)-1;

            cells[player.GamePosition.x, player.GamePosition.y].SetActive(false);
        }

        lastTickTime = PhotonNetwork.Time;

    }
}
```

PlayerControls.cs

```
using ExitGames.Client.Photon;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour, IPunObservable
{
    private PhotonView photonView;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    public Vector2Int Direction;
    public Vector2Int GamePosition;


    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {

        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {

            stream.SendNext(Direction);

        }
        else
        {

            Direction = (Vector2Int)stream.ReceiveNext();

        }
    }



    private void Start()
    {
        photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        GamePosition = new Vector2Int((int)transform.position.x, (int)transform.position.y);
        FindObjectOfType<MapController>().AddPlayer(this);
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) Direction = Vector2Int.left;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) Direction = Vector2Int.right;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) Direction = Vector2Int.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) Direction = Vector2Int.down;

            if (Direction == Vector2Int.left) spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
            if (Direction == Vector2Int.right) spriteRenderer.flipX = false;

            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, (Vector2)GamePosition, Time.deltaTime * 3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you write the class `PlayerControls.photonView` or is this an external package you are using?

Comment: @Christine yea i just added a PlayerControls.cs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PlayerControls.cs`, change `private PhotonView photonView;` to `public PhotonView photonView;`.

This issue is the `private` keyword used in property declaration. This will not allow you to access `photonView` property outside of the `PlayerControls.cs` class. Declaring it as `public` resolves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

PhotonView is a property of the class, that is either declared protected or private.

If you handle the code, then you need to declare it public. If not, then you need to find some kind of other way to access it.

Share some code of the class to help you more.

Comment: added a playercontrols.cs file